# Which is the best way to pass (list)adapters to (list)fragments?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments

I've read several similar questions, but I've not found a convenient solution.

I'm writing an FTP client app, so I have an `Activity` with three tabs (`ListFragment`s): Pending, Completed and Failed transfers. Actual transfers are performed in the background by a `Service`, that updates three respective tables in the DB/`ContentProvider`. My activity uses a `LoadManager` to show the DB content into the tabs.

Main actors in my Activity are:

1. A `ViewPager`
2. The relative `PagerAdapter`
3. The three `ListFragment`s
4. Their relative `ListAdapter`s

So: **which is the best place where to pass `ListAdapter`s to `Fragment`s?**

By now, I pass the adapters to Fragments into the `Fragment getItem(int)` method of the PagerAdapter. Doing so, all works well until you rotate the device. In effect, the Activity is recreated, but fragments are not! It happens that the brand-new PagerAdapter looks into the FragmentsManager and find the fragments, so it doesn't call the getItem method.

My workaround is to put this code in the onCreate method of the activity:

```
List<Fragment> fragments = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();
if (fragments != null) 
    for (int i = 0; i < fragments.size(); i++) 
    switch (i) {
     case PENDING_ID:
         ((MyListFragment) fragments.get(i)).setListAdapter(pendingCursorAdapter);
         break;
         ...
    }
```

It do works fine, but it's tricky and no one ensures me that positions into the `fragments[position]` list is the same given by `getItem(int position)`.

Comment: *but I've not found a convincent solution.* - how about you just let each fragment setup his own adapter(using its dedicated `Loader`)?

Comment: @Luksprog Do you mean into the `onLoadFinished` callback? There I have no reference to the Fragment, nor I know if it exists or not...

Comment: I said that each fragment should implement its own `Loader`, in this case the fragment is available because you'd basically need to let the fragment implement the `LoaderCallbacks`(the Loader will be manipulated by the fragment). Then, once this loader retrieves the data you can setup an adapter with it(for that fragment). When the service updates the data in db then make the `Loader` retrieve the new data. If you use a `ContentProvider` along a `CursorLoader` you get this data updating for free.

Comment: Ok @Luksprog, got it! Nice answer!